# (AWS) Athena: Query Results seem too short

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

My Athena queries appear to be too short in their results. Trying to figure out Why?

Setup:

Glue Catalogs (118.6 Gig in size). 
Data: Stored in S3 in both CSV and JSON format. 
Athena Query: When I query data for a whole table, I only get 40K results per Query, there should be 121Million Records for that query on average for one month's data.

Does Athena Cap query result data? Is this a service limit (the documentation does not suggest this to be the case).

Answer (score 4):

So, getting 1000 results at a time obviously doesn't scale. Thankfully, there's a simple workaround. (Or maybe this is how it was supposed to be done all along.)

When you run an Athena query, you should get a [QueryExecutionId](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution). This Id corresponds to the output file you'll find in S3.

Here's a snippet I wrote:

```py
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
athena = boto3.client("athena")
response: Dict = athena.start_query_execution(QueryString=query, WorkGroup="<your_work_group>")
execution_id: str = response["QueryExecutionId"]
print(execution_id)

# Wait until the query is finished
while True:
    try:
        athena.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=execution_id)
        break
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        time.sleep(5)

local_filename: str = "temp/athena_query_result_temp.csv"
s3.Bucket("athena-query-output").download_file(execution_id + ".csv", local_filename)
return pd.read_csv(local_filename)
```

Make sure the corresponding [WorkGroup](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/athena/workgroup/view-details/primary/home) has "Query result location" set, e.g. "s3://athena-query-output/"

Also see this thread with similar answers: [How to Create Dataframe from AWS Athena using Boto3 get_query_results method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026405/how-to-create-dataframe-from-aws-athena-using-boto3-get-query-results-method)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is a limit of 1000.
You should use `NextToken` to iterate over the results.

Quote of the [GetQueryResults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html) Documentation

> MaxResults The maximum number of results (rows) to return in this
>   request.
>
> Type: Integer
>
> Valid Range: Minimum value of 0. Maximum value of 1000.
>
> Required: No

Comment: From the SDK perspective this makes sense. But in the Console , the query limit exceeds well above 1000. A table that has 121,000,000 records for a select * returns 40,000 records.

Comment: Okay. Didn't know that you are using the CLI SDK. But if CLI returns 40000, the approach is the same. Iterate with help of `NextToken` through your results.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is ***Paginate and count approach :***
Don't know whether better way to do it like select count(*) from table like...

Here is the complete example code ready to use. Used python boto3 athena api
I used `paginator` and converted result as list of dict and also returning count along with the result.

below are 2 methods
First one will paginate
second one will convert paginated result to list of dict and calculate count.

***Note : converting in to list of `dict` is not necessary in this case. If you don't want that.. in the code you can modify to have only count***

```
def get_athena_results_paginator(params, athena_client):
    """

    :param params:
    :param athena_client:
    :return:
    """
    query_id = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=params['query'],
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': params['database']
        }
        # ,
        # ResultConfiguration={
        #     'OutputLocation': 's3://' + params['bucket'] + '/' + params['path']
        # }
        , WorkGroup=params['workgroup']

    )['QueryExecutionId']
    query_status = None
    while query_status == 'QUEUED' or query_status == 'RUNNING' or query_status is None:
        query_status = athena_client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_id)['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
        if query_status == 'FAILED' or query_status == 'CANCELLED':
            raise Exception('Athena query with the string "{}" failed or was cancelled'.format(params.get('query')))
        time.sleep(10)
    results_paginator = athena_client.get_paginator('get_query_results')
    results_iter = results_paginator.paginate(
        QueryExecutionId=query_id,
        PaginationConfig={
            'PageSize': 1000
        }
    )
    count, results = result_to_list_of_dict(results_iter)
    return results, count


def result_to_list_of_dict(results_iter):
    """

    :param results_iter:
    :return:
    """
    results = []
    column_names = None
    count = 0
    for results_page in results_iter:
        print(len(list(results_iter)))
        for row in results_page['ResultSet']['Rows']:
            count = count + 1
            column_values = [col.get('VarCharValue', None) for col in row['Data']]
            if not column_names:
                column_names = column_values
            else:
                results.append(dict(zip(column_names, column_values)))
    return count, results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

res = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=query,
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': '         '  # Replace with your actual database
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': '                            ',  # Replace with your actual S3 output location aws-athena-query-results-129137241730-eu-west-1
    }
)
while True:
    # Get the query execution status
    execution = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=res['QueryExecutionId'])
    status = execution['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
    if status == 'SUCCEEDED':
        # If the query execution succeeded, get the query results
        response = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=res['QueryExecutionId'])
        # Fetch all the rows
        while 'NextToken' in response:
            next_response = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=res['QueryExecutionId'], NextToken=response['NextToken'])
            response['ResultSet']['Rows'].extend(next_response['ResultSet']['Rows'])
            if 'NextToken' in next_response:
                response['NextToken'] = next_response.get('NextToken')
            else:
                break
                
        # Process the results in JSON FORMAT --> WILL  have to parse to pd dataframe
        resultados = response
     elif status == 'FAILED' or status == 'CANCELLED':
            # If the query execution failed or was cancelled, raise an exception
            raise Exception('Query execution failed or was cancelled')
else:
    # If the query execution is still running, wait for a while before checking the status again
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: try to use --> while 'NextToken' in response: