# How to mock AWS athena/awswrangler with moto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena, moto

I am used to mocking most boto3 functionalities with moto.

Recently, I encountered [awswrangler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029782/1059860) to query athena and get the result as a nice pandas dataframe.

wondering if there is a way to mock the functionality?

Comment: I'd check to make sure what you are doing is supported here https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATION_COVERAGE.md

Comment: Awswrangler isn’t on that list. :-/. Guess I’ve to go through using boto3

Answer (score 0):

you can use from moto import mock_athena

```
from moto import mock_athena

class Test:
    @mock_athena
    def test_athena(self):
         pass


#OR you can use this ,this is more useful
class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    athena_service = mock_athena()

    def setUp(self):
    athena_service.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        athena_service.stop()

    def test(self):
        client = boto3.client('athena')
        #whatever you want to test in athena
```