# How can I request a large dataset from Athena without being limited to 1000 rows at a time

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

A solution I am working on requires that I request 100k plus data rows from Athena in a spring api. I am led to believe that only 1000 rows at a time are provided by default. Wondering if anyone has experience with a similar operation and how to request large datasets from Athena without paging

Comment: Possibly helpful for you: [(AWS) Athena: Query Results seem too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328908/aws-athena-query-results-seem-too-short) Specifically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html

Comment: Athena saves the results of queries to an Output location in S3. I wonder if you can run the query, then download the results from S3 instead of through the API? See: [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html)